# Alinhar Verticalmente Objetos Alinhados Horizontalmente

Tags: css, css3

A ideia aqui é `centralizar verticalmente` o `radio button` com seu `label` (alinhados horizontalmente).

Onde estou errando?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<ul class="formasPgto">

 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="pagamento" value="pagseguro" id="pagseguro" />
  <label for="pagseguro">Pag Seguro</label>
 </li>

 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="pagamento" value="boleto"  id="boleto" />
  <label for="boleto">Boleto</label>
 </li>

 <li>
  <input type="radio" name="pagamento" value="cartao" id="cartao" />
  <label for="cartao">Cartão</label>
 </li>

</ul>
```

CSS

```
.formasPgto {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;  
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  border: #000 .3px solid;
  text-align: center;
}

.formasPgto li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  border: #000 .3px solid;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.formasPgto li label, .formasPgto li input[type=radio]  {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está nessas duas linhas, retire isso do `<ul>`:

```
...
line-height:100px;
...
```

Existem várias várias maneiras de centrar verticalmente/horizontalmente elementos em CSS:

1. https://jsfiddle.net/wgoc40bk/2/ Neste caso, mantendo a estrutura html que tem era isto que eu faria
2. Mudando um pouco estrutura HTML, pondo os elementos a centrar numa caixa mãe,  então podemos optar por esta solução: https://jsfiddle.net/wgoc40bk/5/ . Jogamos com os displays (`display:table/display:table-cell`) na caixa mãe (`.formasPgto li`) e criamos uma outra caixa mãe (`<div>`) para nos ajudar nesta tarefa, para agrupar os elementos a centrar. Um exemplo Simples: http://www.vanseodesign.com/blog/demo/vertical-centering/table-cell.php
3. Aproveitando a estrutura html que criamos no ponto dois podemos também optar por: https://jsfiddle.net/wgoc40bk/6/ . Também uso muito essa maneira, definindo `position:relative` na caixa mãe (`.formasPgto li`) e na caixa a centrar (`div`) definimos entre outras coisas a `position:absolute`. Aqui temos manualmente de definir uma `height` para a nossa `<div>`, senão por default a position absolute define a altura como 100%

Aconselho sempre a colocar um wrapper (caixa mãe), nestes ultimos dois casos uma `div`, a agrupar os elementos a centrar

PS: Só não escrevi o CSS todo aqui para não ficar muito extenso... Nesses exemplos acima tem os CSS desenvolvidos

Comment: Não entendi muito bem. Vamos lá: a caixa da ul com width: 800px height: 100px. Conteúdo interno alinhado horizontalmente: text-alig: center. Cada li com width: 250px height: 50px. vertical-align: middle. Dessa forma a li não alinha verticalmente

Comment: Neste caso pode usar padding este exmplo: https://jsfiddle.net/wgoc40bk/2/

Comment: Parece que label não dá para alinhar verticalmente com vertical-align: middle. É isso mesmo? E nesse caso o recurso é usar padding?

Comment: Ha `vertical-align: middle`  daria o efeito que quer se a caixa mão tivesse display table e o elemento a centrar `display: table-cell;`. Vou completar a min resposta

Comment: Então entendi corretamente. Alguns elementos aceitam o vertical-aligment sem display table, já outros não. Neste caso, vou preferir usar padding mesmo. Obrigado. Estou entrando no mundo tableless.

Comment: vertical-aligment é util por exemplo também para elementos alinhados. Brinque com o vertical-align neste exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/87vL52fz/ , aqui o alinhamento é feito em relação aos outros elementos 'irmãos'